# xcode no remotes found

Tags: git, xcode5, raspberry-pi, push

I have a repository server that I set up on a raspberry pi. I've given it a static external ip using a dynamic dns and done all the necessary git stuff (i.e up to the point of adding the remote for the particular repository:

git add remote myAlias git@my.domain:1234/absolute/url/to/repository

where 1234 is the port used for port forwarding (which is setup and working).

I can connect via putty (on windows) but when I add this as a remote to XCode 5.1 and try to "push" it says "no remotes found".

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

I'm new to all this stuff so I'm not sure where I might be going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use git from the command line?

Comment: From the command line, the remote is there. I use "git push myAlias master" and after a while I get a connection time out message and "could not read from remote repository" and it asks me to check the access rights and that the repository exists

Comment: Well that rules Xcode out of the equation.  You might have more luck using ssh with a private/public keypair, the password to which is on the Keychain.

Comment: I see. I'll guess I'll give that a go. Thanks.